# Adobe AEM sidekick not showing components

Tags: adobe, aem

No components show up in my sidekick on one of my pages. I've enabled them on the designs tab and still no luck. I've also tried resizing window, inspect the dom to see if they are there and they aren't. Any ideas?

Comment: Component group is set? Could you please post a `.content.xml` as an example?

Comment: Are they showing up on other pages.. and not on just this page? Can you also look at your error.log file [ aeminstall/crx-quickstart/logs] and see if there are any errors when you deploy code to AEM? This shows if the code/components are even making it to AEM.

Answer (score 4):

@Anthony Try the following :

- Ensure component group property is added as shown in the screenshot below.
- Make sure your components node name is not as same as its jcr:title. eg: if your component node name is 'infoslider', don't have jcr:title as 'infoslider'.
- Go to design mode and check if your component is listing.
- If you do have additional properties like allowedParents, ensure it is set to appropriate value. eg: allowedParents=*/parsys
- Finally, taken from this [link](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-3/developing/components.html) ->The child node cq:editConfig (of type cq:EditConfig) defines the edit properties of the component and enables the component to appear in the Sidekick.
  Note: if the component has a dialog, it will automatically appear in the Sidekick, even if the cq:editConfig does not exist.

[image]